# Faster method for dividing two matrices in 8 small matrices

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Here is my code for dividing two matrices:

```
def divideM1(X,Y):
  n=len(X)
  a=[[col for col in row[:len(row)/2]] for row in X[:n/2]]
  b=[[col for col in row[len(row)/2:]] for row in X[:n/2]]
  c=[[col for col in row[:len(row)/2]] for row in X[n/2:]]
  d=[[col for col in row[len(row)/2:]] for row in X[n/2:]]
  e=[[col for col in row[:len(row)/2]] for row in Y[:n/2]]
  f=[[col for col in row[len(row)/2:]] for row in Y[:n/2]]
  g=[[col for col in row[:len(row)/2]] for row in Y[n/2:]]
  h=[[col for col in row[len(row)/2:]] for row in Y[n/2:]]

  return a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

def divideM2(X,Y):
  n=len(X)
  a=[[0 for i in range(n/2)] for j in range(n/2)]
  b=[[0 for i in range(n/2)] for j in range(n/2)]
  c=[[0 for i in range(n/2)] for j in range(n/2)]
  d=[[0 for i in range(n/2)] for j in range(n/2)]
  f=[[0 for i in range(n/2)] for j in range(n/2)]
  e=[[0 for i in range(n/2)] for j in range(n/2)]
  g=[[0 for i in range(n/2)] for j in range(n/2)]
  h=[[0 for i in range(n/2)] for j in range(n/2)]

  for i in range(n/2):
      for j in range(n/2):
        a[i][j]=X[i][j]
        b[i][j]=X[i][j+n/2]
        c[i][j]=X[i+n/2][j]
        d[i][j]=X[i+n/2][j+n/2]
        e[i][j]=Y[i][j]
        f[i][j]=Y[i][j+n/2]
        g[i][j]=Y[i+n/2][j]
        h[i][j]=Y[i+n/2][j+n/2]
  return a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
```

If I use time.time() it seems method 2-"divideM2" is faster than method 1 -"divideM1" but why is that?
Is there a better method to divide ?

Edit1:
Interestingly when I am using time.time():

```
start = time.time()
print("method1")
for i in range(10000):
  1>2
divideM2(a1,a1)
end = time.time()
t1=end-start
print t1 ,"m1"

start = time.time()
print("method2")
for j in range(10000):
  1>2
divideM1(a2,a2)
end = time.time()
t2= end-start
print t2, "m2"

if t1>t2:
  print "method 2 is faster"
else:
  print "method 1 is faster"
```

I always get "method 2 is faster" even if I am comparing "divide1" by itself. Can someone explain this as well?

Comment: My two questions are:
1) Why is divide2 faster than divide1?
2) Is there a better method?

Comment: This calls for [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/)!

Comment: Why do you repeat the code for the second matrix? You can just divide one into 4 matrices, and then call this method twice.

Answer (score 1):

I think method 2 is faster because you only use 2 loops instead all the `for` loops you use in the first method.

About doing it in another way, you can try `numpy.split`. Here is the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html).

Comment: But I also use multiple for loops for initializing multiple sub arrays in method 2